# Delphi 10.2: TApdComPort ошибка при попытке закрытия СОМ порта

Tags: delphi

Приложение под Windows, написанное Delphi 10.2, работает с СОМ портами используя TurboPower AsynchPro A407_D140 (тип TApdComPort).

Код создания и открытия СОМ порта стандартный:

```
uses AdPort, AdPacket;

...

ApdComPort := TApdComPort.Create(nil);
with ApdComPort do
begin
  AutoOpen      := False;
  ComNumber     := 3;
  Baud          := 19200;
  Parity        := pNone;
  StopBits      := 1;
  SWFlowOptions := swfNone;
  PromptForPort := False;
  try
    Open       := True
  except
    raise Exception.Create('Невозможно открыть СОМ порт! ' + 
    IntToStr(ComNumber))
  end
end

ApdDataPacket := TApdDataPacket.Create(nil);
with ApdDataPacket do
begin
  ComPort        := ApdComPort;
  StartCond      := scString;
  EndCond        := [ecString];
  StartString    := #$73#$D0#$E8#$21#$1E#$90;
  EndString      := #$A1#$07#$B2#$C9#$57;
  IncludeStrings := True;
  PacketSize     := 255;
  TimeOut        := 2148;
  OnPacket       := ApdDataPacketPacket;
  Enabled        := True;
end
```

Код закрытия СОМ порта

```
ApdDataPacket.Enabled   := False;
ApdDataPacket.OnPacket  := nil;
ApdDataPacket.ComPort   := nil;
FreeAndNil(ApdDataPacket);

ApdComPort.Open := False;
FreeAndNil(ApdComPort);
Application.ProcessMessages;
```

Запуск на Windows 7,8 и выше проходит нормально.

Но на XP при закрытии порта возникает ошибка:

Access violation at address 00662552 in module "MyStream.exe". Read of address 00000086.

Приложение зависает наглухо и закрыть его удается только с помощью Диспетчера Задач.

В журнал событий Windows пишется событие:

Тип: Ошибка Код: 1002

Зависшее приложение MyStream.exe, версия 1.0.0.0, зависший модуль hungapp, версия 0.0.0.0, адрес 0x00000000.

Но!!!

То же самое приложение под Windows, написанное Delphi 6, используя TurboPower AsynchPro A404_D60 работает без ошибок.

Как лучше всего на уровне приложения разрулить эту очевидно несовместимость? Можно как-нибудь средствами например TurboPower AsynchPro A407_D140 проверить драйвер, возможность работы с СОМ портом на текущей системе?

Comment: Вы уверены, что проблема именно  в закрытии? Отладчик показывает где ошибка? Попробуйте в коде закрытия оставить только три строки `FreeAndNil(ApdDataPacket);
ApdComPort.Open := False;
FreeAndNil(ApdComPort);`

Comment: Надо запускать под отладчиком на WinXP и смотреть, в каком конкретно месте возникает ошибка.

Comment: На данный момент уверен, что именно в закрытии. Уже пробовал так делать

Comment: Пока нет возможности запустить под отладчиком

Comment: Всем спасибо за комментарии, проблема решилась - закрывать СОМ порт до вызова ApdDataPacket.OnPacket  := nil;
ApdDataPacket.ComPort   := nil;
FreeAndNil(ApdDataPacket); Остается вопрос - почему раньше такого не было.